# How do I display an image over 50% of width of large and small screens?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to display a banner image across 50% of the width of the screen.

The following javascript code works for my desktop but not on my iphone. The image is very small.

```
var width = screen.width;
return <img src="http://test.com" width=' + width/2  />'
```

I thought maybe width should be calculated like so?

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
```

This doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: `<img src="x.png" style="width:50%;height:auto" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need javascript for this, this code will work great:

```
img{ 
 width:50%;
}
```

however, if you want to use that bit of javascript it's probably not working on mobile because you didn't set the viewport tag, paste this in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

**CSS:**

```
img{ 
 width:50%;
}
```

or you can use separate class like this as per suggestion given

```
img.width50{ 
 width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Just a point - I would give the image an id or class and style that otherwise all your images will be 50% wide